# If $f(x)=\min\left\{-|2x-4|,\;x^2-4\right\}$, then what is maximum value of $f(x)$?

Tags: geometry

> If $f(x)=\min\left\{-|2x-4|,\;x^2-4\right\}$, then what is maximum value of $f(x)$?

So first I plot these function over graph, then I found intersection points which are $(-4),(2)$, so I guess $-4$ will be minimum. I don't know this step is correct or not.

Comment: There is no minimum...taking a very large $x$ gives a function value which is a large negative number.  You were asked to find the maximum.

Comment: Yes. But  function is first including minimum? By comparing then 2 will be the answer?

Comment: Not following.  Yes, the function $f(x)$ has a minimum in its definition.  But there is no minimum value for $f(x)$, it goes to $-\infty$.  There is a maximum value, however.  The maximum value for $f(x)$ is not $2$...I don't think that's what you meant.

Comment: @lulu, the maximum value of the function $f(x)$ is $0$ and it is attained for $x=2$. Actually, the OP wanted to say that $2$ is the maximum point of the function, not its maximum value (which is $0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Desmos, you can graph your function like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rtai2nv7gs). But to show your work, you wanna understand the given function more. An equivalent way to write the $f(x)$ is:

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^2 - 4 & \text{, if } - |2x-4| > x^2 - 4 \\
- |2x-4| & \text{, otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now we solve $-|2x-4| > x^2 - 4$ in order to write $f(x)$ in a simpler way. There are many methods to do that. Here's one of them:

$$
-|2x-4| > x^2 - 4 \\
\Leftrightarrow |2x-4| < 4 - x^2 \\
\Leftrightarrow 
\begin{cases}
4 - x^2 > 0 \\
-(4 - x^2) < 2x-4 < (4 - x^2)
\end{cases} \\
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
-2 < x < 2 \\
-(4 - x^2) < 2x-4 \\
2x-4 < (4 - x^2)
\end{cases} \\
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
-2 < x < 2 \\
x^2 - 2x < 0 \\
x^2 + 2x - 8 < 0
\end{cases} \\
\Leftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
-2 < x < 2 \\
0 < x < 2 \\
-4 < x < 2
\end{cases} \\
\Leftrightarrow
x \in (0, 2)
$$

So now $f(x)$ can be rewritten as such:

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x^2 - 4 & \text{, if } x \in (0,2) \\
-|2x-4| & \text{, if } x \in (-\infty, 0] \cup [2, +\infty)
\end{cases}
$$

Now you can graph the function in each part and determine the maximum.

Comment: You explained it more clearly thanks for it, can we use Differention in it to find min,max?

Comment: Yeah you can. But for the absolute value part, a simple $f'(x) = 0$ isn't enough. I remember someone (probably Michael Penn) said that you need to also look at points where $f'(x)$ does not exist. Alternatively, you can consider more cases to remove the absolute value sign.

Comment: $(4−x^2)<2x−4<(4−2x^2)$...is this by mistake how 2 comes in $4-2x^2 here$

Comment: My bad it was a typo lol

Comment: It is okay, Can I contact you if it is not problem to you?

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)$ does not have a minimum on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ as lulu mentioned.

Your approach using graphing should work to find the maximum of the function. To graph the function $f$, you need to identify when $-|2x-4|$ is less than/ greater than $x^2 -4$. We then choose whichever of the two is smaller to construct our graph of $f(x)$. This can be done by finding the intersection points as you said. Your graph for $f(x)$ should be entirely below/ on the x-axis if you graphed right.

Comment: I didn't understand how to select less than/greater than? I simply draw the graph where line is intersecting over (2,0) so this can be maximum

Comment: If you are able to somewhat accurately sketch the graphs for $-|2x-4|$ and $x^2-4$, it should be clear when one is greater than the other. For example, after [graphing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/on0ax1qz1p) both, we see that the function $x^2-4$ is greater than $-|2x-4|$ on the interval $(-\infty,0)$.

Comment: Next, identify which function is greater on the intervals $(0,2)$ and $(2,\infty)$. We choose these intervals since they are "in between" the points of intersection you found at $x=0$ and $x=2$. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes. I understand it properly as you are explaining vert clearly. I draw the same graph and I took 2 as maximum? Maybe incorrect so what should we do now? Comparing these intervels?

Comment: After [graphing](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fbklrtl8fw) $f(x)$, we see than the maximum occurs at $x=2$. Is this what you meant? The maximum value _occurs at_ $x=2$, but the maximum value itself is $f(2)$, which equals 0.

Comment: I want to show my work, how to upload my picture? As you did like desmos

Comment: I guess answer is zero as I found something interesting in graph

Comment: By using graph it is easy to find the answer, but in exam how can we find intervels 
and these functions and get who is greater and lower by putting random infinte value?